# How to increase the max connections in Postgres 12?

Tags: postgresql

I want to increase max_connections up to 3000. How much RAM is required-current 60GB RAM? How should the postgresql.conf file be set up in that case?

If any formula please share it with me?

Comment: 3000 concurrent connections is way too high unless you do have a high-end server with at least 256 CPUs and extremely fast SSDs. And if you really, really want to do that, upgrading to Postgres 14 is pretty much mandatory as it improved performance with such configurations substantially. But the better solution is to use connection pooling in your application.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the maximum connections for a 60GB machine, Data storage:ssd, CPUs number: 10?

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tuning-max_connections-in-postgresql/